# Function with if case to merge two columns or three in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve an interesting problem and would like any suggestions.

What I'm trying to do is merge two dataframes in three columns but if the third one in the first dataframe has a nan value then only merge the first two.

Example:

---DataFrame 1---

| Number | Number2 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | One |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 2 | Three |

---DataFrame 2---

| Number | Number2 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | One |
| 2 | 2 | Two |
| 2 | 2 | Two.5 |
| 3 | 2 | Three |
| 3 | 2 | Three.5 |
| 4 | 2 | Four |

---Result---

| Number | Number2 | Name | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | One | One |
| 2 | 2 |  | Two |
| 2 | 2 |  | Two.5 |
| 3 | 2 | Three | Three |

So far I tried to do a function for this.

```
def merge_three_or_two(row):
        if row['Name'] == np.nan:
            row = pd.merge(row, df2,  how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2'], right_on = ['Number','Number2'])
        else:
            row = pd.merge(row, df2,  how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2','Name'], right_on = ['Number','Number2','Name2'])
    
df1 = df1.apply(merge_three_or_two, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use .isna().any() in the condition:

```
if df1.Name.isna().any():
    print(df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Number', 'Number2']))
else:
    print(df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2','Name'], right_on = ['Number','Number2','Name2']))
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion, however, for some reason it only shows the results of the first case, as it it doesn't consider the second case even if the column Name isn't empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge `df1` and `df2` dataframes on `'Number','Number2'` columns on 1st phase/step, then just drop rows that match the additional condition:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['Number','Number2'], right_on=['Number','Number2'])
df3.drop(df3[df3['Name'].notna() & (df3['Name'] != df3['Name2'])].index, inplace=True)
print(df3)
```

---

```
  Number  Number2   Name  Name2
0       1        2    One    One
1       2        2    NaN    Two
2       2        2    NaN  Two.5
3       3        2  Three  Three
```